# Is it safe to run WebGoat locally in my office laptop for demonstration?

Tags: security, owasp

I'm giving a presentation about OWASP & WebGOAT application in my office. I was wondering if its safe and legal to install WebGoat in my office laptop.

The reason I'm asking this question is because I see the following warnings in the README page of webgoat

"Thank you for downloading WebGoat!

This program is a demonstration of common server-side
application flaws.  The exercises are intended to
be used by people to learn about application penetration
testing techniques.

WARNING 1: While running this program your machine will be 
extremely vulnerable to attack. You should to disconnect
from the Internet while using this program.

WARNING 2: This program is for educational purposes only. If you
attempt these techniques without authorization, you are very
likely to get caught.  If you are caught engaging in unauthorized
hacking, most companies will fire you. Claiming that you were
doing security research will not work as that is the first thing
that all hackers claim."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe and legal. You are going to use it for presentation. It is installed on your laptop. Its mean when you will give presentation, you will attack on your own laptop. So this is legal and no harm in it.